# Using Android Camera2, app gets stuck indefinitely in STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE or STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2

I'm using the [Android Camera2 API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary). I would like to know when is the appropriate time to:

1. show the **TakePicture** button initially (i.e. the camera is ready to capture
   a picture).
2. show this button again (if the process of taking a picture fails, and of course when done) because I hide it when clicking on it (to capture a picture).

I tried `takePicture.setVisibility(View.GONE)` in `lockFocus()` and `takePicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` in `unlockFocus()`.
While this works most of the time, sometimes the button disappears and never appears again (when the process of taking a picture fails I guess) especially when clicking on it very quickly (as soon as it appears on the screen). No errors and no crash happen at this point.

The code is taken from [googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/tree/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic).

**Update:**

I tried `takePicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` inside `onCaptureSequenceCompleted`. The button does appear but the process of capturing a picture is not re-initiated when clicking on it (See [this seven-second video](http://youtu.be/yees4bpHhZQ)). When this happens, the `onCaptureFailed` is not called. However, **it gets stuck indefinitely in `STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE`or `STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE`** because of **`aeState`** which doesn't satisfy the `if` condition.

```
           case STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE: {
                // CONTROL_AE_STATE can be null on some devices
                Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                if (aeState == null ||
                        aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE ||
                        aeState == CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_STATE_FLASH_REQUIRED) {
                    mState = STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE;
                }
                break;
            }
            case STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE: {
                // CONTROL_AE_STATE can be null on some devices
                Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                if (aeState == null || aeState != CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE) {
                    mState = STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN;
                    captureStillPicture();
                }
                break;
            }
```

Comment: Hi, i am also facing same issue,are you find any solution?

Comment: @Rajesh I switched to using another library https://camerakit.io/

Answer (score 1):

i think it should be like this,

```
 case STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE:
              {
                JQLog.d(TAG, "STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE");
                // CONTROL_AE_STATE can be null on some devices
                Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                if (aeState == null
                    || aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE
                    || aeState == CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_STATE_FLASH_REQUIRED
                    || aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_CONVERGED) {
                  state = STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE;
                }
                break;
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

When it fails to take a picture, the `CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback`'s `onCaptureCompleted` will not be called, so your `takePicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` in `unlockFocus()` which is called inside `onCaptureCompleted` will not be called, then the button is disappeared.

You should handle the situation when the capture request fails. `onCaptureFailed` and `onCaptureSequenceCompleted` in `CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback` will fulfill your requirement, and I prefer to use `onCaptureSequenceCompleted` because it will be called no matter the capture request fail or succeed. However, you may also need consider about the abort situation, which is relevant to the callback method `onCaptureSequenceAborted`.

See [CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback) for the full docs.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I added `takePicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` inside `onCaptureSequenceCompleted`. The button does appear but the process of capturing a picture cannot be re-initiated when clicking on it. Please watch this 7 seconde video: https://youtu.be/yees4bpHhZQ

Comment: add callback method `onCaptureFailed` to see the failed reason

Comment: When the situation on the video occurs, only `onCaptureSequenceCompleted` is triggered. The `onCaptureFailed ` is not called!

Comment: the app actually gets stuck indefinitely in `STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE` or `STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE`.

Comment: @HichemAcher Hi,Are you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Rajesh I switched to using another library https://camerakit.io/